# How to initialize a constant array in heap memory using C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, constants

In C++, we can allocate heap memory for a dynamic array, but how can we initialize it if it's a **read only** array? Here is an example:

```
const char* str = new char[3];
```

After operating this statement, the system seems to initialize variable `str` with garbage value implicitly which means i cannot change its value since it has a constant qualifier. So how can i creat a constant string in heap memory and intialize it explicitly?

If i want to creat a object in heap memory, i need a pointer to the object. But if it's constant, i cannot even change it with the pointer after its creation in heap memory. So it became a vicious circle for me.

Comment: `const char* str = new char[3]{'a', 'b', 'c'};` Any C++ book teaches it.

Comment: `But if it's constant, i cannot even change it with the pointer after its creation in heap memory` Yep, you can't change it because it is constant. Why do you want to do this? Why is `const char* str = "my string";` not enough here?

Comment: @273K: OP stated in the question that they want to create a "constant string", which implies that they want to create a null-terminated string. The solution in your comment is not null-terminated.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel There's no such thing as a "null-terminated string". OP doesn't mention it. You perhaps mean null-terminated char array.

Answer (score 2):

You can start with `char *` modify the array, then convert it to `const char *`:

```
char *str = new char[3];
// str[i] = ...
const char *cstr = str;
```

But unless you're trying to practice dynamic memory management, none of this should be necessary. Just use `std::string` or `std::vector<char>`.

Answer (score 1):

Your operator new call doesn't allocate `const` memory. It gets converted to `const` when you assign it to the variable. The solution is to make a temporary variable that's not const, write the data to it and then finally convert it to a const pointer:

```
#include <cstring>
#include <memory>

std::unique_ptr<const char[]> PutBytesOntoHeap(const char* data, size_t size)
{
    std::unique_ptr<char[]> result(new char[size]);
    memcpy(result.get(), data, size);
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In current c++ [avoid calling new/delete explicitly](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#r11-avoid-calling-new-and-delete-explicitly), only use it internally in datastructures (and even then std::make_unique is prefered). So use [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) (or alternatively std::string/std::string_view)

@273K Also note most C++ books (teachers, online material) are out of date.

```
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<char> str{ 'a', 'b', 'c' }; // this will do the memory allocation for you

    // for local use (when a legacy api needs a pointer, otherwise don't use)
    const char* ptr = str.data();

    return 0;

    // std::vector goes out of scope
    // will free the allocated memory (so you can't forget to call delete[])
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> if it's constant, i cannot even change it with the pointer after its creation in heap memory

In

```cpp
const char* str = new char[3];
```

you actually create a non-`const` `char` array and assign it to a `const char*`. You could just assign it to a `char*` instead, make the changes you want and then return a `const char*`. Example:

```cpp
auto str = []() -> const char* {
    char* rv = new char[3];
    rv[0] = '1';
    rv[1] = '2';
    rv[2] = '\0';
    return rv;
}();
```

> how can i creat a constant string in heap memory and intialize it explicitly?

You use `new const char[]` with an initializer:

```cpp
auto str = new const char[3]{'1', '2', '\0'};
```

A helper function could look like this:

```cpp
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

template <std::size_t N>
auto make_const_cstring(const char (&s)[N]) {
    return [&]<std::size_t... Is>(std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
        return new const char[N]{s[Is]...};
    }(std::make_index_sequence<N>());
}

int main() {
    auto str = make_const_cstring("Hello world");
    std::cout << str << '\n';
    delete[] str;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

If you want to use an array after the function that created it returns, allocate that array in the heap, not in the run-time stack. Expression new T[size] allocates a new array with size variables in it, each of type T. Remember that an array is treated just like a pointer to the first thing in the array. So expression new int[25] has type int*. Statement

int* A = new int[25];

allocates a new array of 25 ints and stores a pointer to the first one into variable A.

The size can be given by any expression that yields an integer. For example, if you already have an integer variable called n that currently holds 50, then

double* B = new double[n];

allocates an array of 50 doubles.

Comment: The question _"How to initialize a constant array in heap memory using C++?"_ / _"how can i creat a constant string in heap memory and intialize it explicitly?"_ seems lost in this answer

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).